# Combining two scripts in applescript

Tags: applescript, backup

I'm a complete newbie to applescript and my new external backup HDD made it necessary for me to work with it. As it is quite noisy I wanted to write a script that mounts the disk (if it is unmounted), runs the backup and then ejects the backup disk again (Code A). So far so good. In order to eject the disk after backup has finished I found a piece of code to check if a process is still running (Code B). It returns 1 if the backup process (backupd) is still alive and 0 if it is finished.
I am struggling now with combining those two pieces. I would like code B to keep checking after the backup has started if backupd is still running and if it is done go to the next step and eject the disk.

I just can't get code B running in code A and also the needed loop confuses me a bit. Any help is really greatly appreciated!! I can't imagine it's that tricky just too much for my imagination  Thanks for helping me restoring peace and quietness

**Code A:**

```sh
set myVolumeLabel to "Time Machine"

tell application "Finder"
    set diskDev to do shell script "diskutil list | grep \"" & myVolumeLabel & "\" | grep -o > 'disk[0-9]*' "
    if not (disk myVolumeLabel exists) then
        
        do shell script "diskutil mountDisk " & diskDev
        do shell script "/System/Library/CoreServices/backupd.bundle/Contents/Resources/backupd-> helper >/dev/null 2>&1 &"
        
        (* Checking if the backupd process is still running should go here I suppose.*)
    else
        do shell script "diskutil eject /Volumes/'Time Machine' " & diskDev
    end if
    
end tell
```

**Code B**

```sh
on check_process(marker)
    set the_processes to (do shell script "ps -A")
    return (the_processes contains marker)
end check_process

if check_process("/backupd") then
    set x to "1"
else
    set x to "0"
end if

---display dialog x buttons {"OK"} default button 1
```

Mac OS X (10.6.8)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that what you want to do is rather low-level kind of "system stuff" and that more of the code should be done in the shell.

I'm learning both AppleScript and Unix shell-scripting (the bash shell to be precise, which is the default shell in OS X).

Most of your AppleScript here is really mostly shell scripts inside of AppleScript.

It seems like in this case, the right tool for the right job is a shell script.

You may not want to learn a whole 'nother programming language right now, so I'll give you a couple of thoughts.

If you end a shell-command with an ampersand "&" inside of the quotation marks, then AppleScript will NOT wait for the shell script to complete but rather it will return immediately, putting the process on a separate thread and will return a process id.

If you don't terminate a shell-command with an ampersand, then AppleScript will wait for the command to finish  before proceeding.

You can try the following experiment.  Type in the following command into Terminal.app:

sleep 10

It will take 10 seconds before you get control back in Terminal.

If you type the following command,

sleep 10&

You will get control back immediately and will get a process id back to refer to the process which you have started.

Well, again, it seems to me that the whole script is best written as a bash script, possibly using a little bit of Automator or AppleScript to kick things off.

Mac shell (bash) tutorial:
http://tidbits.com/article/7003

-- Kaydell
[Let me be your guide](http://learnbymac.com)

Comment: thank you kaydell for your reply and infos! I stuck with the shell scripts and eventually got it to work... To be honest the result is not very pretty but it works. But still thanks a lot!